# how to scale to fit the background image objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, background

I am trying to set the image without any uiimageview,now I have the image but it is repeated horizontally twice I want to scale and fix it to screen size how do u do that??

I have tried some methods but nothing worked out

below is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
[[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_themee.png"] drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
// self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:image];
// UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(self.view.frame.size);
// [[UIImage imageNamed:@"background_themee.png"]   drawInRect:self.view.bounds];
// UIImage *image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
// UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"background_themee"]];
 // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
}
```

thanks in advance for your suggestions!!

Comment: simple this line is enough `self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage  imageNamed:@"background_themee"]];`

Comment: @GeneCode ok let my try it!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`colorWithPattern` will always repeat the image over the view. If you open in iPhone, it maybe appear 2 times image. And if you run on iPad, there might show 4 image. So it is not good for background image.

What you need is a UIImageView with contraints properly set and contentMode set to AspectFill.

Comment: yes it worked thank you!! and you can up vote if u think it is a valid question:)

Answer (score 1):

[image]

you can select scale to fill or aspect fill/fit according to your need